# Destroying nodes in a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, destructor

Suppose I have a certain binary tree. I used `new` to create nodes, but now I want to delete them in the destructor:

```
void BinaryTree::recursiveDestructor(Node *& noeud){
    if (node != 0) {
        recursiveDestrutor(node->leftTree);
        recursiveDestructor(node->rightTree);
        delete node;
        node = 0;
    }
}
```

And I use the method in the destructor

```
BinaryTree::~BinaryTree(){
    recursiveDestructor(root);
}
```

Is there a way to just use a `while` or a `for` loop in the destructor instead of calling recursively a method inside the destructor? It would be faster using a loop and avoid using a method inside the destructor. If I can't use a loop, is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: You need some stack anyway, search for [binary tree iterative traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=binary+tree+iterative+traversal)

Comment: Yes. Use a queue. In the `BinaryTree` destructor, push the non-null root on the queue, then loop by (a) popping the head of the queue. (b) pushing the non-null left and right pointers of the node just popped on to the queue, (c) delete the node just popped. Repeat. When the queue is empty you're done.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you show me what it might look like using c++?

Comment: @notaprogrammertoday Posted. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can breadth-delete a tree with a [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). Note: this is hammered out online with no syntax checking, but hopefully you get the idea:

```
BinaryTree::~BinaryTree()
{
    if (!root)
        return;

    std::queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(root);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        Node *p = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (p->left)
            q.push(p->left);
        if (p->right)
            q.push(p->right);
        delete p;
    }
}
```

Note: it is *imperative* that the nodes are *not* child-lifetime managed. I.e. a node *cannot* auto-delete it's children on destruction. Doing so would invoke a double-delete and a boatload of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a recursive dtor? Just do

```
Node::~Node()
{
   delete left;  // assuming left and right are both an instance of Node
   delete right;
}

BinaryTree::~BinaryTree() {
   delete root;
}
```

The dtor will be called down the whole tree working through all the nodes.

Comment: *"Why do you need a recursive dtor"* - FYI, that *is* a recursive dtor.

Answer (score 0):

If your tree nodes store their parent it is possible to find the following node from any position and you could do a while loop on that but it will take more time than the recursive form (because the call to next() will require more than just a single node step half the time where the recursive-descent never takes more than a single step to find the next node to free).